# JavaScript not working after minification

Tags: javascript, minify

Sorry for not copying entire code but I think this should be enough.  My code runs fine before minification with Microsoft AJAX Minifier.  The program does a good job of renaming all the variables to nice small meaningless names but I am seeing a very strange bug that I can't figure out.

On line 532 there is a `var dt;` which is why dt shows up in Chrome's local variable list but when I execute line 592 it says

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: dt is not defined".

Any ideas?

[image: stepping through code]

Comment: Looks like dt has no var declarer?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's going to be really hard for anybody to help.

Comment: have you tried google's closure compiler? see if it also has this issue? if so, you might have a partition in your code that does not follow standarrds and the compilers can't handle.

Comment: How is it even possible to get a reference error in line 592? Such errors occur only when accessing an undeclared variable which doesn't seem to be the case here..?

Comment: Google's closure compiler has no issues however it rewrites the code so much it causes issues with other parts of my code.  not insurmountable but tedious if I need to make changes since I need to modify the output each time.

Comment: the part in pink is notes chrome adds to show you the value of variables

Comment: Okay, so let's chalk it up to microsoft having done a botched up job at writing a javascript compiler.
If you want to have output minified in a meaningful way, have you considered building the objects with strings? `var foo = {}; foo['bar'] = true` The string wont get optimised(hopefully) and at the end you can still access it with foo.bar. or you use `foo={'bar':true}` that way you still have string notation for the variable parts.

Comment: can you check if you have a `let dt` somewhere later in that scope? Your error might be caused by temporal dead zones.

Comment: @le_m no there is no let dt anywhere in the code.  lets are only found in for loops and are all single letter variables.  n,t,i,r,u to be precise

Comment: i have found that the problem is some how after line 592 since if I delete everything after that it runs with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (the only?) possible scenario for why you might see a Reference Error for a variable assignment for a variable previously declared with `var` is:

```
var dt;
{
  dt = []; // Reference error due to hoisting & TDZ
  let dt;
 }
```

Similar in spirit is (const is similar to let regarding TDZ):

```
var dt;
{
  dt = []; // Reference error due to hoisting & TDZ
  const dt = 1;
}
```

For an explanation search for "Temporal Dead Zones" and "hoisting". In short: let is block level scoped and a let declaration is hoisted to the beginning of the block, but any access to that variable before encountering the let statement results in a Reference Error.

Comment: very useful thing to know but definitely not the problem here.  I methodically went through the code looking for `let dt` or `let ...,dt` and found none.  then just to be thorough i replaced every instance of let with var(yes I know they are not exactly the same but a quick way to check if this may be a problem) and the problem still persists.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse How about `const`?

Comment: Downvoter: OP asks for 'any ideas' regarding reference errors after var declaration; if there is an issue with this answer please let us know. Thanks :)

Comment: yes const was the problem.  Thank you so much and I learned something very useful.

Comment: You're welcome! I am still interested though... Is that an issue with your original code or caused by an error in Microsoft's minifier?

Comment: it is caused by microsofts minifier reusing variable names after they are no longer needed.  Replacing const with var causes the minified version to work just fine.  My code does not actually require the const or let so I will just leave them out so the minifier will work properly.  Google Closure Compiler does a better job of minifying but as mentioned earlier it is to aggressive for my application.